# Can I interconnect all echo pins from multiple ultrasonic sensors?

Tags: gpio, stm32f103c8t6, hc-sr04

I want to use (probably) four ultrasonic sensors [HC-SR04](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/13959).
These use a trigger pin and echo pin.

For the echo pins, I want to connect them to a timer with 'Combined Channels PWM Input on CH1', and the Input Trigger set to TI1FP1, so it is able to automatically time the high time of an echo.

However, since I don't want to use 4 timers, I want to interconnect all echo pins (and trigger the trigger pins of the sensors one by one).

Would this work, or is it not adviced to 'set' a signal to an echo pin when another echo pins becomes high?

Or should I use an IC with logical ORs? or is there a better/easier way?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcN82J.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I got it by someone and he doesn't know the source, so I don't have a datasheet, this is something similar: [Information](http://www.electroschematics.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/HCSR04-datasheet-version-1.pdf)

Comment: Why not use a multiplexer IC?

Comment: @MarshallEubanks I have to check what that does (limited electronic knowledge).

Comment: Add the link to the datasheet so we're all using the same one and we don't all have to search for it.

Comment: Depends how the echo pins are wired inside the sensor.

Comment: @Transistor  I don't have a datasheet, updated my answer with some information (last paragraph).

Comment: @immibis not sure, I got it by someone, without any source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, those sensors use a TTL level output signal for echo, so you'll have use an or gate or diodes plus a resistor to implement an or gate.  You can drive all the triggers with a single output, although you won't be able to tell which sensor each echo comes from and multiple echo pulses that overlap will appear as a single long pulse.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCPa00.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Sounds like an easy solution, depending on how many I want to use (4 in principle).

Comment: Just in case, I check for multiplexers (probably CD4051BE will do), but this is an elegant sultino for if I don't want to use an IC.

Answer (score 1):

The Echo pin is a TTL output<sup>1</sup>, according to the [datasheet for the HC-SR04](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Sensors/Proximity/HCSR04.pdf).  Don't wire the Echo outputs together directly.  If one output is in a high state and another output is in a low state and they are connected together, then one of the outputs can burn.
Instead, combine the outputs using an OR gate IC.

<sup>1</sup> <sub>If it were open-collector or an open-drain output, you could create a *wired OR* with a pull-up resistor.</sub>